# Conservative functors.

Tags: category-theory

A result by Freyd proves that any locally small category $C$ has a conservative functor $F: C \to $ Set.

> P.J. Freyd
>   On the concreteness of certain categories
>   Symp. Math. Azzoguidi, Vol. IV (1970), pp. 431-456

Set is not the only category with this property.
In fact, since there is a conservative functor Set $\to$ Grp, Grp has this property. Also Mod(A) has this property and many other categories.

I am looking for necessary and sufficient condition to have this property.

Also, I am looking for a sound notion of morphism between category with this property.

Comment: Disclaimer ahead of time in that I'm not a category-theorist, but why all of the painting terminology? Feels like it complicates this more than helping

Comment: Feels like you are working up to some mighty pun...

Comment: Ok, I will fix this.

Comment: It looks like these categories deserve a definition!

Comment: I propose to call a category $\cal K$ such that there is a conservative functor $F : {\cal C}\to \cal K$ for every $\cal C$ a "painter". The reason is obvious, isn't it?